# html - How to make file list lose focus only when click other file on list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, focus

Like on google drive i have file list on my web and i want it to lose focus only when user click other file on a list but not lose focus to anywhere of web.

[google drive's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PILgN.jpg)

I see some example that put the focus back to the previous focus point after losing focus but that won't work for my need.

here is my code for each line of files

```
<ul class="midarea-content-line" tabindex="3">
        <li><a class="midarea-content-name">FileName</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-owner">Owner</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-date">Date</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post the jquery code part to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
$(".midarea-content-line").click(function () {
  $(".midarea-content-line").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.midarea-content-line{
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.midarea-content-line.active{
   color: #fff;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="midarea-content-line active" tabindex="3">
        <li><a class="midarea-content-name">FileName</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-owner">Owner</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-date">Date</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="midarea-content-line" tabindex="3">
        <li><a class="midarea-content-name">FileName</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-owner">Owner</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-date">Date</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="midarea-content-line" tabindex="3">
        <li><a class="midarea-content-name">FileName</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-owner">Owner</a></li>
        <li><a class="midarea-content-date">Date</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class called active. And give an id to each line.

```
<ul class="active ......">
```

Whenever the user clicks a file.

CSS:

```
.active { background-color: red; }
```

JS:

```
    ('#id').click(function () {  
        $(".midarea-content-line").each(function() {
        if $(this).hasClass('active') {
          $(this).removeClass('active')

        }
     })
        $(this).addClass('active')
    })
```

id is the id of line which you want to focus.
Something like this. This is untested code just to give you an idea.